# Porting C++11 std::thread to boost::thread compile issues

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, boost-thread, boost-move

I'm trying to port C++11 std::thread code to VC9 (VS 2008) using boost::thread. The 'equivalent' C++11 code below compiles fine on msvc12:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

void thFun(int i) 
{
    std::cout << "Hello from thread " << i << " !\n";
}
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> workers;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        auto th = std::thread(&thFun, i);
        workers.push_back(std::move(th));
        assert(!th.joinable());
    }
    std::cout << "Hello from main!\n";
    std::for_each(workers.begin(), workers.end(), [](std::thread& th)
    {
        assert(th.joinable());
        th.join(); 
    });
    return 0;
}
```

I'd like to port the code to C++03 using the msvc9 compiler and Boost 1.55. How do I resolve the following compile error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/container/vector.hpp>

void thFun(int i) 
{
    std::cout << "Hello from thread " << i << " !\n";
}
void foo(boost::thread& th)
{
    assert(th.joinable());
    th.join(); 
}

int main()
{    
    boost::container::vector<boost::thread> workers;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        BOOST_AUTO(th, boost::thread(&thFun, i));
        workers.push_back(boost::move(th));
        assert(!th.joinable());
    }

    std::cout << "Hello from main!\n";
    BOOST_FOREACH(boost::thread& t, workers)
    {
        foo(t);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compile error is:

```
d:\program data\boost\boost_1_55_0\boost\preprocessor\iteration\detail\local.hpp(37): error C2770: invalid explicit template argument(s) for '::boost::move_detail::enable_if_c<boost::enable_move_utility_emulation<T>::value&&!boost::move_detail::is_rv<T>::value,const T&>::type boost::forward(const ::boost::move_detail::identity<T>::type &)'
          d:\program data\boost\boost_1_55_0\boost\move\utility.hpp(78) : see declaration of 'boost::forward'
          d:\program data\boost\boost_1_55_0\boost\container\vector.hpp(1797) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::container::allocator_traits<Alloc>::construct<T,T>(Alloc &,T *,const P0 &)' being compiled
          with
          [
              Alloc=std::allocator<boost::thread>,
              T=boost::thread,
              P0=boost::thread
          ]
          d:\program data\boost\boost_1_55_0\boost\container\vector.hpp(1791) : while compiling class template member function 'void boost::container::vector<T>::priv_push_back(const T &)'
          with
          [
              T=boost::thread
          ]
          d:\work\boostthreadscratch\boostthreadscratch\boostthreadscratch.cpp(19) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::container::vector<T>' being compiled
          with
          [
              T=boost::thread
          ]
```

Comment: Is that the full error message? In what line of your source does the error appear?

Comment: [This](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/tti/doc/html/the_type_traits_introspection_library/tti_func_templates.html) might be related. Have you tried to replace `BOOST_AUTO`?

Comment: Before including any boost headers, try this: `#define BOOST_THREAD_USES_MOVE`. See [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/emulations.html#thread.emulations.move) for reference.

Comment: @Albert Full message edited in. Error appears related to line 19 `boost::container::vector<boost::thread> workers` but the actual error is on line 23 `workers.push_back(boost::move(th));`

Comment: using #define BOOST_THREAD_USES_MOVE works. Compiling in vc9 correctly now.

Comment: #define BOOST_THREAD_USES_MOVE uses boost::move by default. boost::move emulation usage isn't mentioned in the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this at the beginning:

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_USES_MOVE
```

See [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/emulations.html#thread.emulations.move) for reference. It enables the emulation provided by Boost.Move (`boost::move`) for `boost::thread`, which is disabled by default in Boost.Thread version 2 (which might be used by MSVC9 in your case).